Flutter AlertDialog Container minimum width size controll

Hello mates
i was making instagram colon app with flutter and i wanted to making this pop up page but when i tried to make container size less than 100, it wasn't work and i couldn't find the way can u tell me how can i make that container width size more less then 100

SliverAppBar(
              floating: true,
              snap: true,
              toolbarHeight: 60,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    CupertinoIcons.heart,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    CupertinoIcons.paperplane,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              centerTitle: false,
              // Instagram Logo Button
              title: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print(kToolbarHeight);
                  showCupertinoDialog(
                    barrierDismissible: true,
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => Dialog(
                        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,

                        // clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        alignment: FractionalOffset(
                            0,
                            (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top +
                                    kToolbarHeight) /
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          child: BackdropFilter(
                            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 20, sigmaY: 20),
                            child: Container(
                                width: 10,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
                                    color: Colors.grey[800]!.withOpacity(0.6)),
                                child: const Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(CupertinoIcons.person_2,
                                            size: 32, color: Colors.white),
                                        SizedBox(width: 12),
                                        Text('Following',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18))
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 12,
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(CupertinoIcons.star,
                                            size: 32, color: Colors.white),
                                        SizedBox(width: 12),
                                        Text('Favorates',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18))
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )),
                          ),
                        )),
                  );
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Instagram',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 32,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.chevron_down,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

finding new widgets for fix,
tried to search on google and chargpt also
looking official Docs and stackoverflows
checking widget's pharams

Have you tried reducing the widget of the container inside the ClipRRect? its currently 10, try reducing.

yeap ofc almost near the 100 values it wasnt become smaller
i just added 10 for show it extremly

changed alertdialog -> actions
and it worked
